# Getting error while creating table with primary key and constraints sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is one of the tables I created:

```
create table take
   (SID integer references student(SID),
    CID integer references course(CID),
    FID integer references faculty(FID),
    semester varchar(10) primary key constraint chk check(semester in('Fall','spring')),
    year_a integer ,
    grade integer)
```

While inserting values:

```
insert into take 
values(105,2,1001,'spring',2009,9)
```

I get the following error

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*take*_0184BAF3D4160567'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.take'. The duplicate key value is (fall).

Pls help

Comment: Which DBMS are you use?

Comment: Are you sure you're inserting `spring` in column `semester`? Because MSSQL complains about `fall`...

Comment: i use sql server 2012 and yes i did try inserting fall/spring in semester only

Comment: I think you may have gotten the order wrong. Try this: "constraint semester varchar(10) primary key check(semester in('Fall','spring'))..."

Comment: Without seeing all the T-SQL that led to your error its tough to make suggestions. One problem that I can see right away with the [take] table is that you have defined the primary key as the [semester] column with two defined values. This means that are only going to be able to store two records in the [take] table (i.e. one for 'Fall' and one for 'Spring' regardless of the SID, CID, and FID column values.

Comment: Try to specify column names in insert it could be the way.

Comment: Once again i tried by creating another table    :   create table product(
maker varchar(10),
model varchar(10) unique,
types varchar(10) constraint chk check(types in('PC','printer','laptop')))... i was able to insert values :-) but for the previous one, still i am unable to do so

Comment: Well, you've defined `semester` to be able to store one of two values only - `fall` or `spring`, and you've made it the primary key. So once you've stored one row with `fall` and a second with `spring`, your constraints prohibit any further inserts. I **highly doubt** that you want to make just `semester` with only two possible values the primary key ...

Comment: `semester varchar(10) primary key constraint chk check(semester in('Fall','spring')),` Only allow to stored one record for fall and another for spring, no duplicate allowed in primary key constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've defined `semester` to be able to store one of two values only - `fall` or `spring`, and you've made it the primary key (the key that uniquely identifies each row).

So once you've stored one row with `fall` and a second with `spring`, your constraints prohibit any further inserts.

I **highly doubt** that you want to make just `semester` with only two possible values the primary key ...

I believe what you probably meant to do is:

- limit the `semester` to `fall` and `spring`
- create a primary key on `(semester, year)` so that you could have `fall 2013`, `spring 2014`, `fall 2014` etc.

In that case, you need to change your create script to something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Take
   (SID INT REFERENCES student(SID),
    CID INT REFERENCES course(CID),
    FID INT REFERENCES faculty(FID),
    Semester VARCHAR(10) 
        CONSTRAINT CHK_Semester CHECK(Semester IN ('Fall','spring')),
    Year_a INT,
    grade INT,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Take PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(Semester, Year_a)
)
```